# Issue Extracting HTML Data Via Android

Tags: java, android, jquery, html, jsoup

I have an android jsoup based app which I'm using to pull data from an HTML table however I'm unable to extract data from the following url:

http://sheriff.org/apps/arrest/results.cfm?lname=&fname=

I simply need a bit of assistance figuring out how to parse the data from this particular table.

I know I need to change a parameter here:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
                Element tableHeader = doc.select("tr").first();

                for (Element element : tableHeader.children()) {
                    aa.add(element.text().toString());
```

This is my first time extracting HTML data via java/androind and I'm not sure exactly how it can be done.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

SOURCE:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> aa = new ArrayList<String>();
        ListView lv;
        final String URL = "http://example.com";

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            new MyTask().execute(URL);
        }

        private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog prog;
            String title = "";

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                prog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                prog.setMessage("Loading....");
                prog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                try {
                    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
                    Element tableHeader = doc.select("tr").first();

                    for (Element element : tableHeader.children()) {
                        aa.add(element.text().toString());
                    }

                    title = doc.title();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return title;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                prog.dismiss();
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,aa);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<table class="datagrid">
        <tr>
            <th>User Name</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Location</th>
        </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><a href="redirector.cfm?ID=c4e7a7ea-0832-4cdb-9b38-4cbdde8c07bc&page=1&&amp;lname=&amp;fname=" title="501207593">501207593&nbsp;</a></td>
                <td>LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME&nbsp;</td>
                <td>M&nbsp;</td>
                <td>Location1</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><a href="redirector.cfm?ID=6dfb8f0b-949a-49a1-b3bf-b361544ee5d8&page=1&&amp;lname=&amp;fname=" title="501302750">501302750&nbsp;</a></td>
                <td>LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME&nbsp;</td>
                <td>M&nbsp;</td>
                <td>Location2</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><a href="redirector.cfm?ID=b638597e-0319-4eea-a2d4-d763d43125eb&page=1&&amp;lname=&amp;fname=" title="531201804">531201804&nbsp;</a></td>
                <td>LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME&nbsp;</td>
                <td>M&nbsp;</td>
                <td>Location3</td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Did you get any solution for this ,how to extract data of each tag based on class name and display it on screen

Comment: Can you offer more assistance? I'd really appreciate it and I would be more than happy to try & accept your answer...

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can extract all data of a link by using the HttpURLConnection.

```
HttpURLConnection con=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

InputStream is=con.getInputStream();

FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(storeDir+"/"+filename);

int data=0;

  while((data=is.read())!=-1){

    fos.write(data);

   }

is.close();

fos.flush();

fos.close();
```

You might want to check this site for more information http://dev-androidapps.blogspot.com/2013/09/web-download.html.